# Calculate balance in Power Query with M

Tags: powerquery

I have two tables:

The first holds the refunds sent to customers:

| Customer ID | Refund ID | Total refunded |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ref1 | $100.00 |
| 1 | Ref2 | $150.00 |
| 1 | Ref3 | $200.00 |
| 2 | Ref4 | $300.00 |

and the second links the above table with the relevant credit notes:

| Customer ID | Credit note Allocation ID | Refund Amount Allocated | Refund ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CnAll1 | $100.00 | Ref1 |
| 1 | CnAll2 | $100.00 | Ref2 |
| 1 | CnAll3 | $50.00 | Ref2 |
| 1 | CnAll4 | $100.00 | Ref3 |

What I want to achieve is a third table with a combination of the two with the refund balance not allocated for each refund

| Customer ID | Refund ID | Total refunded | Credit note Allocation ID | Refund Amount Allocated | Balance not allocated to any Credit note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ref1 | $100.00 | CnAll1 | $100.00 | $- |
| 1 | Ref2 | $150.00 | CnAll2 | $100.00 | $- |
| 1 | Ref2 | $150.00 | CnAll3 | $50.00 | $- |
| 1 | Ref3 | $200.00 | CnAll4 | $100.00 | $100.00 |
| 2 | Ref4 | $300.00 |  | $- | $300.00 |

- Refund Ref1 is matched with the relevant credit note in full. The value of the credit note is = the refund. No balance not allocated
- Refund Ref2 is matched in full as well against two credit note. The value of the credit notes is = the refund. No balance not allocated
- Refund Ref3 is matched only for $ 100 because the value of the credit notes is $ 100. The balance not allocated is $ 200-100=$ 100
- Refund Ref4 is not matched at all therefore the balance not allocated is $ 300

I cannot find the way to calculate the correct balance in all the scenarios above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mostly a question of doing a few merges, then shifting the ID row by one for comparison

Load your second table as **Table1** into powerquery

Load your first table into powerquery with code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer ID", Int64.Type}, {"Refund ID", type text}, {"Total refunded", Int64.Type}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Customer ID", "Refund ID"}, Table1, {"Customer ID", "Allocated Refund ID"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Credit note Allocation ID", "Refund Amount"}, {"Credit note Allocation ID", "Refund Amount"}),
RefundByID=Table.Group(Table1, {"Allocated Refund ID"}, {{"Refund Amount", each List.Sum([Refund Amount]), type nullable number}}),
#"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Table1", {"Refund ID"},RefundByID, {"Allocated Refund ID"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "Table1", {"Refund Amount"}, {"Refund Amount.1"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Table2",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Refund Amount.1"}),
//shift Refund ID down one row
      shiftedList = List.RemoveFirstN(#"Replaced Value"[Refund ID],1) & {null},
      custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Replaced Value") & {shiftedList},
      custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value") & {"Next Row"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "Balance", each if [Refund ID]=[Next Row] then 0 else [Total refunded]-[Refund Amount.1]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Refund Amount.1", "Next Row"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]